# multiple icons possible for one app?

Tags: iphone

can the same app have different icons so that a user can select the icon he/she desires.
ex. user1 wants icon x 
    user2 wants icon y
both users using the same app.

Answer (score 2):

No, you cannot change the icon. It is not possible.

Comment: This is true, with the caveat that the icon may change between different screen sizes (that is, iPhone vs. iPhone 4 vs. iPad), though I don't know if Apple will accept the app if the icons are too different.